# I am trying to get all from elements from a particular div and then validate them

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, validation

I am trying to get all form elements from a particular div and then try to validate them,but my code is not working for select box and radio buttons,
Here my function

```
function validateForm(currentTab) {
    var valid = true;
    var div = currentTab;
    $(div).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea', 'input:radio, input:checkbox').each(function() {

        //  console.log($(this).attr('name')+ " " +$(this).attr('type'));
        if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
                $(this).css("border", "1px solid red")
                valid = false;
            } else {
                $(this).css("border", "")
            }
        }
    });

    return valid;
}
```

Comment: Paste `$(div).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea','input:radio, input:checkbox')` in the developer console and check if its selects all the fields that you want

Comment: For select boxes you may have to add the `option` tag

Comment: it showing for all select box undefined

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you search param is breaking into 2 strings instead being just one parameter as selector:

```
$(div).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea', 
    <-- here  -->  'input:radio, input:checkbox')
```

instead:

```
 $(div).find('input:text, input:password, input:file, select, textarea, input:radio, input:checkbox')
```